# How do I deploy a project to multiple clients?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, deployment, project, clients

I am completely a beginner.

I am developing an ASP.NET application called *College Management System*. So how do I complete the architecture for this so that the application can be used by different colleges?

This application is going to be used by various colleges and universities. So if I get the tips about how the project is deployed to the clients so that all can access the application.

One last question please:

Every college must have their own application, but still all details must be available with the university as well.

University can have control of these colleges.

Comment: As it’s a web application, it can be accessed everywhere. What exactly you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a Windows server running IIS with the feature ASP.NET.

If you want your application run separately for each colleges, you need different domains (one server or many does not matter). If you want to deploy a project, you can use the build in publisher from Visual Studio (VS).

You need to install web deploy on the server and give it access (depending on the amount of servers, you might need to create multiple sites in IIS). Publish it on each server for colleges to have their own installation. Now you need to create an system administrator panel for universities to give them the ability to make their appropriate changes.